# Affinity - Only run x number of pods per node in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I can only find documentation online for attaching pods to nodes based on labels.
Is there a way to attach pods to nodes based on labels and count - So only x pods with label y?

Our scenario is that we only want to run 3 of our API pods per node.
If a 4th API pod is created, it should be scheduled onto a different node with less than 3 API pods running currently.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not schedule by *count* of a specific *label*. But you can avoid co-locate your pods on the same node.

### Avoid co-locate your pods on same node

You can use `podAntiAffinity` and `topologyKey` and `taints` to avoid scheduling pods on the same node. See [Never co-located in the same node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#never-co-located-in-the-same-node)